# Can't create equations to solve linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

### Problem

Suppose that vectors $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ have the following property: for each $i$ the sum of all vectors except $x_i$ is parallel to $x_i$. If at least two of the vectors $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ are not parallel, what is the value of the sum $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n=?$

### Attempted solution

I tried to start from the simplest case: 2 vectors: $x_1, x_2$. The condition: for each $i$ the sum of all vectors except $x_i$ is parallel to $x_i$ means, that $x_1 \parallel x_2$. But it contradicts to condition: "at least two of the vectors are $\not\parallel$". So, for 2 vectors such set doesn't exist.

For 3 vectors we get the following:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 = a_1 \cdot (x_2 + x_3)\\
x_2 = a_2 \cdot (x_1 + x_3)\\
x_3 = a_3 \cdot (x_1 + x_2)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

After we add up all these equations, we get:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = a_1 \cdot (x_2 + x_3) + a_2 \cdot (x_1 + x_3) + a_3 \cdot (x_1 + x_2)$

### Difficulty

I have no idea, what to do next. And how to use the condition: "at least two of the vectors are not parallel". This condition means, they are linearly independent: $a_1 \cdot x_1 + a_2 \cdot x_2 = 0 \leftrightarrow a_1 = 0\; \& \;a_2 = 0$. But I don't have any equations with zero here. And I don't understand, how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: A vector is parallel to $x_i$ if and only if it’s a multiple of $x_i$. For each $i$ let $y_i$ be the sum of the vectors other than $x_i$. Then for all $i$ we have

$$x_1+\ldots+x_n=x_i+y_i=\alpha_i x_i$$

for some scalar $\alpha_i$. Now suppose that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are not parallel. What can you infer from $\alpha_ix_i=\alpha_jx_j$?

Comment: "What can you infer from $\alpha_ix_i=\alpha_jx_j$?" - I can infer, that they a parallel, cause one vector is equal to another, multiplied by scalar. It leads to a contradiction with the condition: "$x_i$ and $x_j$ are not parallel".

Comment: This makes the problem even more weird.

Comment: @user4035: The fact that they are not parallel means that they are linearly independent; what does that tell you about $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$?

Comment: "what does that tell you about $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$?" linearly independent vectors can be equal if and only if $\alpha_i = 0$ and $\alpha_j = 0$. So, the sum must be 0. Thx.

Comment: @user4035: You've got it. You're welcome.